# What's the appropriate template system to export an HTML output as pdf or odt?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, templates, pdf

I'm a python newbie trying to build my first app with Google App Engine (and Python) that save time when you need to write a form contract (like a house rental or car rental contract (link: http://contractpy.appspot.com ).

I'd like to know what is the best and simplest way to export the final output (at the moment, an HTML page) to a pdf, odt or googledoc file. In other words: instead of copying and pasting, the user gets what he wants: the contract file ready to print.

This is the current state of the output (a sample):

http://contractpy.appspot.com/your_contract?resident=Nicola%20Tesla&nacionality=Serbian-American&SSN=1234567&driverLicense=0000001&email=&witness=Carl%20Sagan&owner=House%20owner&contractType=House%20Rental%20Contract&city=Smiljan

But I'd like to get something like this:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8TXLR_e14aCeVVfZVZGdUVNUEE

How could I get this?

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render an html file with some [paged media](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-page/) tags. for example:

```
@page {     
    size: 21cm 29.7cm;
    margin: 1.5cm;
}
```

than convert it with Conversion API and serve the output file

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to the [Conversion API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/conversion/overview).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same type of issue a while ago and couldn't find a solution to build the report on my own.

After some research, I went for Docmosis. They offer the report generation as a SAAS solution. It took me about one hour to generate custom reports. Their documentation is very good and their support has been great so far. It can generate .doc and .pdf documents.

The only problem I see is that their standard documentation is for Java. However their SAAS solution talks through JSON or XML. If you are able to generate JSON or XML from Python, I guess it will be easy for you to generate the documents you are looking for.

Cheers,

Hugues

Answer (score 0):

As far as my experience with browser engine based conversion tools goes, the documents are overly complicated and usually way several MBs.

I have never used [pandocs](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/index.html), but it might be what you are looking for. My preferred way of conversion to PDFs has been [reportlab](http://www.reportlab.com/), and [sphinx](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) for documentation. For odt you might wanna look into [open office docs](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Python).